# Can libraries (next, remix) that support SSR act like pure proxy servers?

Tags: html, next.js, server, proxy, remix

What I want is to act as an intermediate proxy server that connects servers and clients through those libraries.

The above code imports data (HTML in the form of string) from another domain server (the domain server makes HTML string and throws it)

```json
{
"data": {
"code": "SERVICE",
"title": "Service",
"content": "<html>\n\n<head>\n\t<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n\t<title> 서비스이용약관 </title>\n\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\"\n\t\thref=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/orioncactus/pretendard/dist/web/static/pretendard.css\" />\n\t<style>\n\t\tbody {\n\t\t\tline-height: 2em;\n\t\t\tfont-family: Pretendard, sans-serif;\n\t\t\tpadding: 10px;\n\t\t\tfont-size: 13px;\n\t\t}\n\n\t\tp {\n\t\t\tmargin: 10px;\n\t\t\ttext-align: justify;\n\t\t}\n\n\t\tol,\n\t\tul {\n\t\t\tmargin: 20px;\n\t\t}\n\n\t\tstrong {\n\t\t\tfont-size: 14px;\n\t\t}\n\n\t\ttable {\n\t\t\tborder-collapse: collapse;\n\t\t\tborder: none;\n\t\t\twidth: 100%;\n\t\t\tpadding: 10px;\n\t\t}\n\n\t\tth {\n\t\t\tbackground-color: #d9d9d9;\n\t\t\tborder: 1px solid black;\n\t\t\ttext-align: center;\n\t\t\tpadding: 10px;\n\t\t}\n\n\t\ttd {\n\t\t\tborder: 1px solid black;\n\t\t\tpadding: 10px;\n\t\t}\n\t</style>\n\n</head>\n\n<body>\n\t<p><strong>Shut up and squart !!</strong>~~~~
```

And send the imported HTML to the client. That's All. I think I could use a pure server like Express, but I have to use NEXT or REMIX for other reasons.

Now, we are using SetInnerHTML to insert HTML string as it is. However, if you check the client's data, it is a situation where html is repeated under html.
Is there a way to solve it?

```html
<html>
 <meta>
  <html> //=> ?
```

```js
import { fetch } from '@remix-run/node';
import { useLoaderData } from '@remix-run/react';
import type { LoaderArgs } from '@remix-run/node';
import type { IEhp } from '~/lib/api/@types/ehp';

export const loader = async ({ params }: LoaderArgs) => {
  const { service, type } = params;

  const domain = 'https://example.com/v1';
  const switchService = {
    a: 100,
    b: 200,
  }[service as string];

  const result = await fetch(
    `${domain}/terms/${switchService}/current/${type}`,
  );

  return result;
};

export default function Service() {
  const {
    data: { content },
  } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>() as IEhp;

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />;
}

export function ErrorBoundary() {
  return <div>No Answer</div>;
}
```